# SELECT where group contains values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a plain table with order-supplier relations. It shows which suppliers participated in which order. Obviously one order can have multiple suppliers:

```
+---------+------------+
| OrderId | SupplierId |
+---------+------------+
| O_1     | S_1        |
+---------+------------+
| O_1     | S_3        |
+---------+------------+
| O_2     | S_1        |
+---------+------------+
| O_2     | S_2        |
+---------+------------+
| O_2     | S_999      |
+---------+------------+
```

And I have another table which contains pairs of suppliers like that (input data):

```
+--------------+--------------+
| SupplierId_1 | SupplierId_2 |
+--------------+--------------+
| S_1          | S_2          |
+--------------+--------------+
| S_2          | S_3          |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Note that pairs are unique, so if there is (S_1, S_2) pair there won't be (S_2, S_1) pair. But it's impossible to say in which order the pair will come: it can come as (S_1, S_2) or as (S_2, S_1) but not both.

How can I get IDs of orders having suppliers from these pairs?

For example in this case order with Id O_1 won't be selected because there is no (S_1, S_3) or (S_3, S_1) pair but O_2 will be selected because at least two of its suppliers have a pair (S_1 and S_2).

So basically I need to group up the first table by OrderId and select orders where each order supplier list contains at least one pair from the second table.

Comment: is there any column to use as 'order by'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses two joins:

```
select o1.orderid, p.supplierid_1, p.supplierid_2
from pairs p join
     orders o1
     on o1.supplierid = p.supplierid_1 join
     orders o2
     on o2.supplierid = p.supplierid_2 and
        o2.orderid = o.orderid;
```

This inverts the logic in the question.  Think about the pairs first, and which pairs have the same order with each supplier.